# Ruby then Rails for a beginner web developer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I have a pretty simple question yet I want you to as thorough as possible. I want to jump in into the web development, but I don't know where to start. I've already coded with JS and Jquery. I also have experience in HTML/CSS.

The problem is, these are front-end programming tools. My quest is to create something more back-end, like a little web application (a blog etc.) and to accumulate a lot of useful experience in this sphere.

At the moment I'm learning Ruby. After I've finished the basics, I want to move on to ROR framework, which I've heard is quite amazing.

Is this a wise choice? Do you any suggestion/comments on this decision, whether it's a dumb path or a great one?

Thank you!

Comment: To speed your learning of Ruby, have a look at [Rubeque](http://www.rubeque.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to create Web applications I would say Ruby On Rails is a great choice. There are a number of great free and paid resources out on the web.

- [codeschool](http://codeschool.com) has realy good paid and free courses on RoR definately check them out.
- after that you should check out [Micheal Hartl's Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). It's a free ebook online that teaches you how to build a twitter clone and it's an awesome resource.
- You can check out [treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com/).They have paid courses and they teach you how to build a facebook clone with file uploads and activity feeds and everything.
- Check out [tutsplus](http://tutsplus.com) they have some good courses on ruby deployment and refactoring with ruby.
- Have a look at [peepcode](https://peepcode.com) they have some awesome videos on topics such as vim(to code real fast) and also a series called play by play if you want to watch how the pros code.
- also if you want to subscribe to some workshops check out [Thoughtbot learn](https://learn.thoughtbot.com).you should check out their beginner and intermediate workshops.They also have a workshop for testing with Rails, screencasts on various topics and some awesome books.
- And definitely have a look at [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/).It's an awesome series of screencasts by Ryan Bates about a wide range of topics for RoR.You can find both paid and free screencasts on the site.

Comment: That's basically what I wanted to know, thank you very much. Best answer so far!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn is to actually develop something as you mentioned. For ROR, you can use: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book. In my opinion this is a great tutorial. You can polish your Ruby while doing ROR development.

Comment: I agree with your idea of learning while developing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking out [Code School](https://www.codeschool.com/). It has a large Ruby track for learning both Ruby and Rails. There's also [Rails Casts](http://railscasts.com/), which contain a ton of knowledge on building Rails apps.

Comment: Thank you for the resources. I've already started learning Ruby on Codeacademy, it is a wonderful site.